# Is SQL Server Compact *ever* OK to use on a web server?

Tags: browser, sql-server-ce

I'd like to host a personal database for about 500 people (1 database per person) on my web server.  A person could possibly share their database with a friend or two.  On my web server, I'd have some web services, perhaps for doing synchronization, and maybe even an ASP.NET Web Forms front end to the database.

If I restart my IIS web server, would this likely cause database corruptions?  Would this be expected to perform ok?

If not Compact, should I instead use SQL Express and create a database in SQL Server for each of my 500 people?

Comment: can you elaborate with why they each need their own database?

Comment: It's a personal contact management application. Each user's database is private to that user.

Comment: It could still a single database.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I'd isolate different users with an "owner id" column rather than different databases.

Comment: I want to keep the database on the web server using the same structure as the one on the desktop.  This way I can share code, and also it'll keep the synchronization strategy more simple.  I don't want to add an "owner id" column to every table, because then I have to remember to filter by this column on *every* query (yuck!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ScottGu says it's OK:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx